# Function on Page Load running yet not working? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to generate a "bus ticket", I want it so when the user chooses one of the available times for a set trip, a new windows appears, once he chose the time I redirect the user to the previous page, I set up a method on Page load that checks if this is the "final part" as in it checks if If the time has already been chosen with a Session set to a Ticket Object, once the time has been chosen, the "trip" is added to the ticket, and the user can choose to add further trips to that ticket but they must start from where the previous one left off, problem is, I have a method that makes it so you can only choose the previous destiny as this trips' origin, but when I finish adding the trip all the destinies appear on my drop down list instead of the only one I set up, here's some of my code:

```
    Ticket theTicket;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.List();//This displays all the origins and values needed to choose when making a ticket
            this.FinalTripStage();//this checks if I'm coming from the "choose time" page and if so finishes adding the chosen time to the trip and the chosen trip to the ticket
        }
    }   

    private void FinalTripStage()
    {
        if (Session["STrip"] != null)
        {
            theTicket= (Ticket)Session["STicket"];
            Trip theTrip= (Trip)Session["STrip"];
            theTicket.TripsTicket.Add(theTrip);
            ListTrips();
            ListOrigin();
            ListDestinies();
            Session["STicket"] = elPasaje;
            Session["STrip"] = null;
        }
    }

    private void ListOrigin()
    {
        theTicket= (Ticket)Session["STicket"];
        Trip trip= theTicket.TripsTicket[gvTrips.Rows.Count - 1];
        if (gvTrips.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.ddlOrigin.Items.Clear();//ddlOrigin is a drop down list displaying cities, trips have an origin and a destiny in form of cities
            this.ddlOrigin.Items.Add(new ListItem(trip.DestinyTrip.NameCity, trip.DestinyTrip.IdCity.ToString()));
            this.ddlOrigin.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ddlOrigen.DataSource = null;
            this.ddlOrigen.DataSource = laAgencia.ListarCiudades();
            this.ddlOrigen.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I've followed the stack trace and the code in FinalTripStage() runs properly and tested outside of page load works fine, yet when the page loads it's as if it never ran and I get the full list of cities to choose in the Origin drop down list.

Comment: Have you tried placing in break points and debugging your application?

Comment: yes, the code in the FinalTripStage() runs properly and the dropdown lists get filled correctly, yet when the page finishes loading it's like it didn't happen, the trip gets added to the ticket yet the drop down list doesn't update

Comment: When are you setting the values for the session? What triggers the page load?